# How to keep cursor inside brackets after method autocomplete in Android Studio 3.6?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to Andriod Studio, but I have been using PHP Storm and Webstorm for years. 
When I type for example `var_dump()` in PHP Storm, autocomplete will finish line for me and put cursor inside brackets (which is logical, because I will probably type something in).
Same goes for Webstorm, if I type `console.log()` autocomplete will finish line for me and put cursor inside brackets.
But If type for example `println()`in Kotlin in Android Studio, cursor will be right after closed bracket.
Tried to find setting to overcome this but with no luck.

I checked settings inside **Settings / Editor / General / Smart Keys** in IDE, but didn't find solution.

Answer (score -1):

Live Templates are what you need, I think. Actually, Android Studio already has one for that. Just type 'sout' inside your Kotlin file and the IDE will create a println() with a cursor inside of it instead of a cursor outside of it. To check this, go to   File>Settings>Live Templates and, on the Kotlin list, search for 'sout'. Maybe this article  can also help you: https://medium.com/google-developers/writing-more-code-by-writing-less-code-with-android-studio-live-templates-244f648d17c7